# searching within contents of a cell in ORACLE db using sql only

Tags: sql

I am writing a standard SQL query that returns, among others, values of column called `DETAILS`:

```
select t.id, t.details
from table_1 t
```

Each cell of the `Details` column has a long text arranged in a specific order.

**Sample text goes like this:**

`description (75535183778272) whereto address1-address amount 23301600 livesat address3`

In other words `Details` cell always contains `description, whereto, amount, livesat categories`. And each of this categories is followed by a value of different length.

The **question** is how to construct a query which would give me only value of Amount category in a cell?

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does 'livesat' always follow 'amount'?  And is there even the remotest chance either of those strings will ever appear elsewhere in the long text?

Comment: Yes, 'livesat' always comes after 'amount'. No, they will not appear elswehere within the given cell.

Comment: This is not how you are supposed to use a database. Why don't you have separate columns for the values?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or not? The answer will depend on the dbms actually used...

Comment: yes, I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
select  t.id, 
        t.details, 
        regexp_substr(t.details, 'amount ([0-9]+)',1,1,null,1) amount 
  from  table_1 t;
```

You may also want to convert the amount into a numeric type immediately.

*PS: My example works for positive integer amount only. You may want to modify it to accept decimal and negative values.*

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select t.id,
       t.description,
       regexp_substr(t.description, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, 6) amount
from table_1 t
```

Assuming the amount is always the 6th element...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Table_1 AS (SELECT 'description (75535183778272) whereto address1-address amount 23301600 livesat address3' AS Details FROM dual)
SELECT
     Details
    ,INSTR(Details, 'amount') + 06  AS amount_Pos
    ,INSTR(Details, 'livesat') AS livesat_Pos
    ,SUBSTR
        (
         Details
        ,INSTR(Details, 'amount') + 06
        ,(INSTR(Details, 'livesat') - INSTR(Details, 'amount')) - 07
        )                    AS Amount_Str
FROM Table_1
;
```